# To disable a listview in a fragment thanks to a view behind

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I want to disable a listview which is in a fragment, when a pop-up appears over the activity (the pop-up is a group of views). I don’t want use the property visibility.gone because I want a style effect : I want use a view color with alpha to simulate a disabled background.

I've tried masking the listview with transparent alpha color. But the edit text of listview are clickable, and scrolling is possible again.

Can I superpose list view and "disable" it thanks to any tips ?

Comment: In your transparent view XML, add `clickable= true` and `focusable=true`.

Comment: great. It does work. Many thanks ! What i have set thanks to you is : 

 android:clickable="true"
 android:contextClickable="true"
 android:focusable="auto"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 android:longClickable="true"

You can add the answer and I vote then for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, Add below attributes to the transparent view:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:contextClickable="true"
android:focusable="auto"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:longClickable="true"
```